# Why python doesn't connect to mysql.connector

Tags: python, mysql

My OS is ubuntu 20.04 and to connect python to mysql I use this code :

```py
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'My password', host = '127.0.0.1', database = 'mydb')
cnx.close()
```

But this error happens :
`Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported`

Then I change my code to :

```py
import mysql.connector
cnx = mysql.connector.connect(user = 'root', password = 'My password', host = '127.0.0.1', database = 'mydb', auth_plugin='mysql_native_password')
cnx.close()
```

and this error happens :
`Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost'`
Please tell me what should I do?

Comment: You resolved the first error, and the 2nd one indicates you provided either incorrect username / password combo or the user does not have appropriate access rights. We really cannot help with these.

Comment: I encountered this issue about 2months ago and I discovered mysql-connector needs to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue about 2months ago and I discovered mysql-connector needs to be updated.

```
Pip install mysql-connector-python
```

in your interpreter. Shutdown your project and start again after the pip installation. Then run your connection code again. It should work fine now. In your importation code, still use

```
 import mysql.connector.
```

when connecting to the database, still use:

```
 cnx = mysql.connector.connect(your parameters as usual)
```